# Condição para verificar variaveis nula não funciona

Tags: html, asp, nullable

Estou a desenvolver um página *ASP (Classic)* e nessa página tenho isto:

```
<%if(textocontrato) = "NULL" Then%>
<td >Texto Contrato</td>
<td ><input type="text" name="textocontrato" value="<%=textocontrato%>" size=30 maxlength=30></td>
<%Else %>
<td >Texto Contrato</td>
<td ><input type="text" name="textocontrato" value="<%=Server.HTMLEncode(textocontrato)%>" size=30 maxlength=30></td>
<%End If%>
```

O que eu quero é que, se o `textocontrato` for `= NULL` executa o *HTML* de cima se não for `NULL` executa o de baixo, no entanto mesmo quando o `textocontrato` é `null` ele executa o debaixo e acaba por me dar erro, por o *HTMLEncode* não está a receber nada. 
O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Já tentou `<%If IsNull(textocontrato) Then%>`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você pode tentar fazer isso de 3 maneiras.

1ª Maneira:

```
<%If IsNull(textocontrato) Then%>
```

2ª Maneira:

```
<%If (textocontrato) == null Then%> //Note que null não tem aspas
```

3ª Maneira:

```
<%If (textocontrato) == "" Then%>
```

Comment: Obrigado, utilizei a 1ª Maneira e funcionou!